# CQRS and Event Sourcing coupled with Relational Database Design

Tags: cqrs, azure-cosmosdb, azure-sql-database

Let me start by saying, I do not have real world experience with CQRS and that is the basis for this question.

**Background:** 
I am building a system where a new key requirement is allowing admins to "playback" user actions (admins want to be able to step through every action that has happened in a system to any particular point).  The caveats to this are, the company already has reports that are generated off of their current SQL db that they will not change (at least not in parallel with this new requirement) so the storage of record will be SQL.  I do not have access to SQL's Change Data Capture, so creating a bunch of history tables with triggers would be incredibly difficult to maintain so I'd like to avoid that if at all possible. Lastly, there are potentially (not currently) a lot of data entry points that go through a versioning lifecycle that will result in changes to the SQL db (adding/removing fields) so if I tried to implement change tracking in SQL, I'd have to maintain the tables that handled the older versions of the data (nightmare).

**Potential Solution**
I am thinking about using NoSQL (Azure DocumentDB) to handle data storage (writes) and then have command handlers handle updating the current SQL (Azure SQL) with the relevant data to be queried (reads).  That way the audit trail is created and that idea of "playing back" can be handled while also not disturbing the current back end functionality that is provided.

This approach would handle the requirement and satisfy the caveats.  I wouldnt use CQRS for the entire app, just for the pieces that I needed this "playback" functionality.  I know that I would have to mitigate failure points along the Client -> Write to DocumentDB -> Respond to user with success/fail -> Write to SQL on Success write to DocumentDB path, but my novice CQRS eyes can't see a reason why this isn't a great way to handle this.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't the [Change Feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-change-feed) let you listen for changes and apply them to SQL Database?

Comment: Change Feed seems to be exactly what I am looking for actually.  I think Dogu's answer more thoroughly fleshes out the architecture that would address my problem.  I would use the ChangeFeed as the "message queue" and a worker role that monitors that queue and handles transactions accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One potential way to think about this is creating a transaction object that has a unique id and represents the work that needs to be done. The transaction in this case would be write an object to document db or write an object to sql db. It could contain the in memory object to be written and the destination db (doc db, sql, etc.) connection parameters.

Once you define your transaction you would need to adjust your work flow for a proper CQRS. Instead of client writing to doc db directly and waiting on the result of this call, let the client create a transaction with a unique id - which could be something like Date Time tick counts or an incremental transaction id for instance, and then write this transaction to a message queue like azure queue or service bus. Once you write the transaction to the queue return success to user at that point. Create worker roles that would read the transaction messages from this queue and process them, write objects to doc db. That is not overwriting the same entity in doc db, but just writing the transaction with the unique incremental id to doc db for that particular entity. You could also use azure table storage for that afaik.

After successfully updating the doc db transaction, the same worker role could write this transaction to a different message queue which would be processed by its own set of worker roles which would update the entity in sql db. If anything goes wrong in the interim, keep an error table and update failures in that error table to query and retry later on.

Comment: This is interesting to me.  I like the architecture layout that you describe (queues feed data stores).  Is there a reason why you would write to a message queue before writing to DocumentDB as opposed to writing to DocumentDB directly (with the transaction object you mention) and monitoring the DocumentDB's ChangeFeed queue (@Matias suggested) to handle the transaction itself?

Comment: Sure queues provide out of shelf functionality to scale out processing of messages by worker roles, features like message visibility, etc. allows a safe way to process a message that client code do not need to handle. Of course in your case within the unit of work there is not much compute but writing the entity to a db so you may say benefits of off loading this to a queue is marginal

Answer (score 1):

This article explained [CQRS pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn568103.aspx) and provided an example of a CQRS implementation please refer to it.

> I am thinking about using NoSQL (Azure DocumentDB) to handle data storage (writes) and then have command handlers handle updating the current SQL (Azure SQL) with the relevant data to be queried (reads).

here is my suggestion, when a user do write operations to update a record, we could always do insert operation before admin audit user’s operations. For example, if user want to update a record, we could insert updating entity with a property that indicates if current operation is audited by admins instead of directly update the record.

Original data in document

```
{
  "version1_data": {
    "data": {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "jack",
      "age": 28
    },
    "isaudit": true
  }
}
```

For updating `age` field, we could insert entity with updated information instead of updating original data directly.

```
{
  "version1_data": {
    "data": {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "jack",
      "age": 28
    },
    "isaudit": true
  },
  "version2_data": {
    "data": {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "jack",
      "age": 29
    },
    "isaudit": false
  }
}
```

and then admin could check the current the document to audit user’s operations and determine if updates could write to SQL database.